# Layout style change when language change android studio

Tags: android-layout

I'm new to Android and I want to know how can I change the layout style. As example, when language is English it will be ltr, but when the language is Arabic it must change to became rtl like the strings-ar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have an specific case where this doesn't apply (and you only support API levels 17 and above), you don't need to change your layout at all.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="Start" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="End" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, when you are in English, it would look something like:

```
      Center
Start
             End
```

But, in Arabic, you'd see:

```
      Center
             Start
 End
```

You can start reading more about this [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

Comment: @Cristina99, you're welcome. Remember to mark the answer and accepted so people know that it worked for you